# Natural interval making (1 dimension clustering) with constraint on the range of the observations in each interval

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, intervals

I have a vector of real numbers on which I want to create natural intervals. In other words, I want to perform 1 dimensional clustering. The constraint is that in each interval, the difference between the highest and the lowest value must be less than a constant c, say 3. I want to obtain a solution having a minimal number of intervals.

I tried to make my intervals using density estimation featuring a gaussian kernel and by decreasing the binwidth until each range is less than 3. However, it does not work since some intervals ranges stay greater than 3 even if I reduce the binwidth a lot. Also, there comes a time where the algorithm starts to create intervals containing no data.

````r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)


# Create vector of real numbers -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set.seed(2019)

nb <- c(10, 23, 17, 16, 20)
x <- c(
  rnorm(nb[1], mean = 20, sd = 0.5),
  rnorm(nb[2], mean = 5,  sd = 0.1),
  rnorm(nb[3], mean = 10, sd = 0.5),
  rnorm(nb[4], mean = 30, sd = 0.8),
  rnorm(nb[5], mean = 18, sd = 10)
)


# Functions ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Returns all local minima given a density object
find_local_mins <- function(density) {
  y <- density$y
  x <- density$x

  ind_mins <- which(y - shift(y, 1) < 0  & y - shift(y, 1, type = "lead") < 0)
  mins <- x[ind_mins]

  return(mins)
}

# Compute differences between max and min value of a vector between breaks
compute_clusters_ranges <- function(x, breaks) {
  clusters <- cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, breaks, Inf))
  splits <- split(x, clusters)
  clusters_ranges <- map_dbl(splits, ~ diff(range(.)))

  return(clusters_ranges)
}


# ----------


# Find and plot intervals using gaussian kernel with binwith of 2 ---------------------------------------------------------------
densite <- density(x, kernel = "gaussian", bw = 2, n = 10000) # Estimate density
mins <- find_local_mins(densite) # Find local minima for clustering

plot(densite, xlab = "x", main = "")
rug(x, ticksize = 0.06)
abline(v = mins, col = rep("blue", length(mins)))

# Compute range (difference between max and min value) for each interval --------------------------------------------------------
cluster_ranges <- compute_clusters_ranges(x, mins)
cluster_ranges # Some ranges are still greater than 3, so we cluster again with a smaller binwith


# ----------


# Find and plot intervals using gaussian kernel with binwith of 1 ---------------------------------------------------------------
densite <- density(x, kernel = "gaussian", bw = 1, n = 10000) # Estimate density
mins <- find_local_mins(densite) # Find local minima for clustering

plot(densite, xlab = "x", main = "")
rug(x, ticksize = 0.06)
abline(v = mins, col = rep("blue", length(mins)))

# Compute range (difference between max and min value) for each interval --------------------------------------------------------
cluster_ranges <- compute_clusters_ranges(x, mins)
cluster_ranges # Some ranges are still greater than 3, so we cluster again with a smaller binwith


# ----------


# Find and plot intervals using gaussian kernel with binwith of 0.659 -----------------------------------------------------------
densite <- density(x, kernel = "gaussian", bw = 0.659, n = 10000) # Estimate density
mins <- find_local_mins(densite) # Find local minima for clustering

plot(densite, xlab = "x", main = "")
rug(x, ticksize = 0.06)
abline(v = mins, col = rep("blue", length(mins)))

# Compute range (difference between max and min value) for each interval --------------------------------------------------------
cluster_ranges <- compute_clusters_ranges(x, mins)
cluster_ranges # The empty interval [36.62, 36.63] have been created

```r

I want to obtain natural intervals for a vector of numeric data. In each interval created, I want the difference between the greatest and the smallest value to be less than 3. I want to obtain this using as few intervals as possible.
````

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the data
2. Find the minimum value m
3. Put everything in [m:m+3) into a bin
4. Repeat with the remaining data?

This fairly trivial approach appears to satisfy the constraints you gave: width at most 3, no empty intervals. As fast as it gets.